# JS function for writing out a word, binary counter style

Tags: javascript, string, binary

How can I create a loop to output any given word like this:

...if the word is 'abcd'

```
a---
-b--
ab--
--c-
a-c-
-bc-
abc-
---d
a--d
-b-d
ab-d
--cd
a-cd
-bcd
abcd
```

in other words, letters appear in binary counter order

```
1000
0100
1100
0010
1010
```

etc.

Thanks

Comment: `(13).toString(2) == "1101";`

Comment: that's how to get a number as binary - I need the letters of a given word to output one by one in binary order... i.e. step 4 of the loop would output "--c-", above. Thanks, though :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var i = 1;
console.log("abcd".replace(/./g, function(c,n) { 
   return (i & (1 << n)) ? c : '-';
}));
```

Just loop `i` from `1` to `(2 ^ length) -1`

Comment: Haha, yours is even shorter! Nice. :)

Comment: this is a great one - short *and* sweet :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you actually want the reverse of binary counting; i.e. for binary it would be

```
0001
0010
0011
```

but you're flipping it.  Which is fine.  The following code counts from 0 to the necessary number (16 for a four-letter word), gets the binary representation for each number, reverses it, and outputs the letters of your word for those places where there's a one in the binary representation.

```
function letterScroller(str) {
   var iterations = Math.pow(2,str.length);//iterate from 0 to 2**wordlength
   var result = "";
   for (i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
       //get the binary representation, pad it, and reverse it
       var bin = reverse(pad(i.toString(2), str.length));

       //loop through binary, adding character of word where there's a 1
       for (j=0;j<str.length;j++) {
           if (bin.charAt(j)=="1") {
               result += str.charAt(j)
           } else {
               result += "-";
           }
       }
       result += "<br />"; //separate lines with HTML line break
   }
   return result;
}

function pad(str, length) {
    while (str.length < length) {
       str="0" + str;
    }
    return str;
}

function reverse (str) {
  return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Comment: Your reverse function is buggy

Comment: I believe you, but can you give me an example of a potential bug?  I'm getting the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doStuff(word) {
    var wordLength = word.length, num = 1 << wordLength;
    var i, bit, wordChars = word.split(""), chars;
    for (var i = 1; i < num; ++i) {
        chars = [];
        for (bit = 0; bit < wordLength; ++bit) {
            chars.push( i & 1 << bit ? wordChars[bit] : "-" );
        }
        console.log( chars.join("") );
    }
}

doStuff("abcd");
```

Answer (score 0):

with KennyTM's code it can be done quite easily

```
String.prototype.reverse = function(){
splitext = this.split("");
revertext = splitext.reverse();
reversed = revertext.join("");
return reversed;
}

str='abcd'; //your string
for(var i=0;i<20;i++){ //a loop of numbers  
  var result='';

  var ii=i.toString(2).reverse();
  for(var q=0;q<Math.max(ii.length,str.length);q++){
    if(ii.charAt(q)=='1'){
      result+=str.charAt(q);
    }else{
      result+='-';
      }
  }      

 document.write(result+'<br>');
}
```

that was fun :)
What do You need that for?

Comment: I want to use it as a kind of progress indicator - like a spinner, but counting up...

Comment: If you replace the '20' with 'Math.pow(str.length,2)', you get the right number of loops...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the short version:

```
var string = 'abcd';
for (i = 1; i < Math.pow(string.length,2); i++) {
    str = "";
    for (j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
        if (i & (1 << j)) 
            str += string[j];
        else
           str += "-";
    }
 console.log(str);
}
```

Enjoy!