# function for writing out a base 7 word, like binary counter style

Tags: javascript, binary

I need a function similar to the ones explained here...

[JS function for writing out a word, binary counter style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328018/js-function-for-writing-out-a-word-binary-counter-style)

...but using base 7 (or others) to generate (count) letters up from A to G
Like so...

```
---a  
---b  
---c  
---d  
---e  
---f  
---g  
--aa  
--ab  
--ac  
--ad  
--ae  
--af    

etc. up to gggg
```

Is there a simple way to change one of those functions to make this happen?

p.s. This is pretty cool...
They used...

```
var iterations = Math.pow(2,str.length)   
and Math.pow(string.length,2)
```

They both work but only because the string length was 4 and the base was 2
inadvertently correct

```
i.e 4^2=16 2^4=16
```

If any other string length was used one of them becomes wrong.

```
i.e. 2^10=1024 10^2=100
```

Comment: That's not base 7, that's base 8 without a 0.

Comment: I actually was trying to figure what base to call it so I thought of an easy example... base 2 would be letters a and b. Using the same reasoning... 7 letters abcdefg would be base 7

Comment: Except you also have `-`, making it 8

Comment: hmmm... No, I thought about this again. In the linked page they used word length 4 abcd and the - hyphen... it is still base two, NOT 5. The number of letters in my word abcdefg actually has nothing to do will whatever the base is. It is the place holders or pattern that matters, can you see it now?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is gives a first start: [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BzBnr/)

It basically just takes a number and converts it to a base 7 number:

```
var map = 'abcdefg';

var n = 13
var out = '';
if(n == 0) out = map.charAt(0) + out;
while (n > 0) {
    out = map.charAt(n % 7) + out;
    n = Math.floor(n / 7);    
}   
// gives "bg" for 13
```

This would imply maintaining a normal counter in decimal system and convert every number.

Note that `aa` in this system does not exit, as `a` maps to `0`.

Comment: Thanks... I got 2 great answers and I'm going to test them and try to get them working for what I need.

Comment: This is what I had in mind to make, just that I couldn't quite think how to do it. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
function change_num(num,base) {
    var lets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    lets = lets.split('');
    if (num / base < 1) {
        return lets[num];
    }
    if (num / (Math.pow(base,2)) < 1) {
        return lets[Math.floor(num/base)] + lets[(num % base)];
    }
    if (num / (Math.pow(base,3)) < 1) {
        var numreturn;
        numreturn = lets[Math.floor(num/(Math.pow(base,2)))];
        numreturn += lets[Math.floor((num%Math.pow(base,2))/base)];
        numreturn += lets[(num % base)];
        return  numreturn;
    }
    if (num / (Math.pow(base,4)) < 1) {
        var numreturn;
        numreturn =  lets[Math.floor(num/Math.pow(base,3))];
        numreturn += lets[Math.floor(num%Math.pow(base,3)/(Math.pow(base,2)))];
        numreturn += lets[Math.floor((num%Math.pow(base,2))/base)];
        numreturn += lets[(num % base)];
        return numreturn;
    }
    if (num / (Math.pow(base,5)) < 1) {
        var numreturn;
        numreturn = lets[Math.floor(num/Math.pow(base,4))];
        numreturn += lets[Math.floor(num%Math.pow(base,4)/(Math.pow(base,3)))];
        numreturn += lets[Math.floor(num%Math.pow(base,3)/(Math.pow(base,2)))];
        numreturn += lets[Math.floor((num%Math.pow(base,2))/base)];
        numreturn += lets[(num % base)];
        return numreturn;
    }

}
```

Works for any base. Couldn't be bothered to write a recursive function so did it the hard way, you can probably infer what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes... thanks, I have to study both for a little while to understand completely what going on :-)