# Implement numbering scheme like A,B,C… AA,AB,… AAA…, similar to converting a number to radix26

Tags: javascript, algorithm, character-encoding, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xnary (like binary but different) counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797736/xnary-like-binary-but-different-counting)

In JavaScript,  I want to implement a numbering scheme in JavaScript so that 1 is A, 2 is B, .... 26 is Z, 27 is AA, 28 is AB .....

For that, heres the code:

```
function convertor(n){

     var x = n-1,
         baseCharCode = "A".charCodeAt(0);

     var arr = x.toString(26).split(''),
         len = arr.length;

     return arr.map(function(val,i){
         val = parseInt(val,26);

         if( (i === 0) && ( len > 1)){
              val = val-1;
         }

         return String.fromCharCode(baseCharCode + val);
     }).join('');
}
```

It seems to work fine, but any ideas to optimize it or another way of implementing it ?

Comment: What problem or non-optimality are you facing?

Comment: Something like this>>? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240637/javascript-convert-numbers-to-letters-beyond-the-26-character-alphabet

Comment: [See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30777592/445295)

Answer (score 4):

This system is similar to [Hexavigesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal) (which starts with A = 0) and is called bijective base-26 (it has no 0). You can convert it using standard base-conversion arithmetic like this:

```
function toDecimal(str) {
    var decimal = 0;
    var letters = str.split(new RegExp());

    for(var i = letters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        decimal += (letters[i].charCodeAt(0) - 64) * (Math.pow(26, letters.length - (i + 1)));
    }

    return decimal;
}
```

Essentially, you convert from hexavigesimal to base 10 as follows. Assume you have to string "AB". What you have then is:

```
1 0 (positions)
---
A B
+ +
| |
| +----> 2 * (26 ^ 0) +
+------> 1 * (26 ^ 1)
       = 28
```

Which gives you 28.

Another example:

```
2 1 0 (positions)
A B C
+ + +
| | |
| | +----> 3 * (26 ^ 0) +
| +------> 2 * (26 ^ 1) +
+--------> 1 * (26 ^ 2)
           = 731
```