# Is there a way to count from last condition x?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a complex set of data that can return 3 different conditions per row.  I need to be able to count the last x rows matching one of the specific conditions.

The following formula has been working well for me, but I have discovered a glitch in one instance of this formula (the formula is replicated at least a dozen times)

`=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,IF(FREQUENCY(IF(AQ:AQ)=1,ROW(AQ:AQ)),IF(AQ:AQ<>1,ROW(AQ:AQ)))=0,FREQUENCY(IF(AQ:AQ=1,ROW(AQ:AQ)),IF(AQ:AQ=0,ROW(AQ:AQ))))))`

Current criteria are as such:
0: Condition x met - Reset counter
1: Condition y met - Increment counter
2: Condition z met - Ignore this row

Therefore this:
1
2
2
2
1
1
0
1
1
1

Should output: 3

This:
1
2
0
2
2
1
2
1

Should output: 2

However the glitch I have encountered isn't resetting the counter when 0 is reached, for example:
1
2
1
2
1
1
2
2
2
2
0

Should output: 0

But in fact is outputting: 4

I have tested all possible conditions with that specific data set and I cannot rectify the issue.  I believe there is an error in the formula (specifically the 9.99999999999999E+307) but I wrote it so long ago that I cannot successfully debug it.  I have tried 1E+306 but the result is the same.

---

EDIT1:  Upon request I have included as stripped down version of the sheet as I can while recreating the issue.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SOXiFMEQelqptBvjcabMZGNgG60TRRbe_b65rzT1bi0/edit?usp=sharing

If you scroll to the bottom of the sheet you can see `Col AQ` has a 0, as a result the value in the cell `AF2` should be `0`.

You will notice in the sheet that I am using Named Ranges.

---

EDIT2: player0's answer was PERFECT!!  <3

I modified the new formula to adapt to my spreadsheet so it could accommodate Named Ranges and drop-down lists.  This question helped me a lot with that:

[Convert column index into corresponding column letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229180/convert-column-index-into-corresponding-column-letter)

The final formula (just FYI) turned out to be:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(
INDIRECT(REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(ROW(), column(INDIRECT($A$1 & Z$1 & "L"))), "[A-Z]+")&
MAX(IF((INDIRECT($A$1 & Z$1 & "L")=0)*(INDIRECT($A$1 & Z$1 & "L")<>""),
ROW(INDIRECT($A$1 & Z$1 & "L"))+1,5))&":"&
REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(ROW(), column(INDIRECT($A$1 & Z$1 & "L"))), "[A-Z]+")), 1))`

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: It's really huge and complex......and the issue is that I can't reproduce the error at a smaller scale because the formula works fine for all instances except this specific one.  I can share the sheet, but I can guarantee I'll get downvoted big time due the size of it :(

Comment: I've posted a sheet - stripped it as best as I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A"&
 MAX(IF((A2:A=0)*(A2:A<>""), ROW(A2:A)+1, ROW(A2)))&":A"), 1))
```

[image: 0]

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1px8CLy1I3putw9E6Lg3JtdIgmlmAHMzmBkLag_M-Hvs/edit#gid=907646020)