# Programmatically test if a Google Sheet cell is in a named range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a Google Sheets `onEdit()` trigger and it only needs to do something if any of the edited cells are in a named range on the spreadsheet.

I have this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editRange = e.range;

  var numRows = editRange.getNumRows();
  var numCols = editRange.getNumColumns();

  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var cell = editRange.getCell(i,j);

      if (isInRange(cell, myNamedRange)) {
         /* Do something clever */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm having trouble writing the `isInRange()` function. It feels like it should be a built-in spreadsheet function, but I can't find anything that looks likely.

**Update:** It struck me overnight that there might be an easier approach. What I actually need is the intersection between two ranges.

Comment: I noticed that you had updated your answer just now. In your script, when multiple cells are edited, each cell is checked `true` or `false` by `if (isInRange(cell, myNamedRange)) {}`. So I proposed the sample script. But I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful. From your updated question, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike: No, I do think your original solution was helpful. Thank you. It's just early in the morning here and I haven't really got going yet :-)

Comment: @Tanaike: I added my update because I thought it might be useful. I wondered if there was a built-in "intersection of two ranges" function. But, having looked now, I can't see one. So I'll go back to your original solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no built-in methods for directly retrieving the intersection ranges of two ranges. If this function tries to be achieved, I think that the sample might be like the sample scripts in my answer. The script for checking one cell is simple. But the script for checking the multiple cells is a bit complicated. If the sample scripts were useful, I'm glad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to check whether a cell is included in the named range.
- You want to create the function of `isInRange`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Flow:

The flow of `isInRange` is as follows.

1. Retrieve named ranges in the active sheet.
2. Retrieve the named range using `myNamedRange`.
3. Return `true` when `cell` is in the named range of `myNamedRange`.
4. Return `false` when `cell` is NOT in the named range of `myNamedRange`.
5. An error occurs when `myNamedRange` was not found.

#### Sample script:

```
function isInRange(cell, myNamedRange) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var namedRanges = sheet.getNamedRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
    var nr = namedRanges[i];
    if (nr.getName() == myNamedRange) {
      var range = nr.getRange();
      var startRow = range.getRow();
      var endRow = startRow + range.getNumRows() - 1;
      var startColumn = range.getColumn();
      var endColumn = startColumn + range.getNumColumns() - 1;
      return cell.getRow() >= startRow && cell.getRow() <= endRow && cell.getColumn() >= startColumn && cell.getColumn() <= endColumn;
    }
  }
  throw new Error(myNamedRange + " was not found.");
}
```

- When this sample script of `isInRange` is used for your `onEdit`, when `cell` is in the named range of `myNamedRange`, the if statement of `if (isInRange(cell, myNamedRange)) {}` is `true`.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the named ranges are retrieved from the active sheet. If you want to change this, please modify the script.

#### References:

- [getNamedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getnamedranges)
- [Class NamedRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range)

---

### Added:

- You want to retrieve the intersection ranges of two ranges.

  - For example, when the named range and the inputted range are "A1:B3" and "B3:C4", respectively, you want to retrieve "B3" as the intersection range.

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve a1Notations from "inputRange".
2. Retrieve a1Notations from "myNamedRange".
3. Retrieve intersection ranges.

In this sample script, the result value is returned an array including the a1Notations. Because the input range might be not continue, and when the array of a1Notations can be also used for [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list).

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var myNamedRange = "sampleNamedRange";  // Please set the name of the named range.
  var inputRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3:C4");  // Please set the range.


  var columnToLetter = function(column) { // <--- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231012/7108653
    var temp, letter = '';
    while (column > 0) {
      temp = (column - 1) % 26;
      letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
      column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
    }
    return letter;
  };

  var result = [];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var namedRanges = sheet.getNamedRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
    var nr = namedRanges[i];
    if (nr.getName() == myNamedRange) {
      // Retrieve a1Notations from "inputRange".
      var iStartRow = inputRange.getRow();
      var iEndRow = iStartRow + inputRange.getNumRows() - 1;
      var iStartColumn = inputRange.getColumn();
      var iEndColumn = iStartColumn + inputRange.getNumColumns() - 1;
      var irA1Notations = [];
      for (var j = iStartRow; j <= iEndRow; j++) {
        var temp = [];
        for (var k = iStartColumn; k <= iEndColumn; k++) {
          temp.push(columnToLetter(k) + j);
        }
        Array.prototype.push.apply(irA1Notations, temp);
      }
      
      // Retrieve a1Notations from "myNamedRange".
      var namedRange = nr.getRange();
      var nStartRow = namedRange.getRow();
      var nEndRow = nStartRow + namedRange.getNumRows() - 1;
      var nStartColumn = namedRange.getColumn();
      var nEndColumn = nStartColumn + namedRange.getNumColumns() - 1;
      var nrA1Notations = {};
      for (var j = nStartRow; j <= nEndRow; j++) {
        for (var k = nStartColumn; k <= nEndColumn; k++) {
          nrA1Notations[columnToLetter(k) + j] = null;
        }
      }
      
      // Retrieve intersection ranges.
      result = irA1Notations.filter(function(e) {return nrA1Notations.hasOwnProperty(e)});
    }
  }
  
  Logger.log(result)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've accepted [Tanaike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60981593/7231) as it gave me a lot of clues that I've found useful while working on this. But, actually, I ended up writing a `rangeIntersection()` function as I mentioned in this morning's update to my question.

The code is here in case anyone else might find it useful.

```
function rangeIntersection(range1, range2) {
  var sheet1 = range1.getSheet();
  var sheet2 = range2.getSheet();

  if (sheet1.getSheetId() !== sheet2.getSheetId()) {
    return false;
  }

  if (range1.getLastColumn() < range2.getColumn() ||
      range1.getColumn() > range2.getLastColumn() ||
      range1.getLastRow() < range2.getRow() ||
      range1.getRow() > range2.getLastRow()) {
    return false;
  }

  var intersectRange = sheet1.getRange(
    Math.max(range1.getRow(), range2.getRow()),
    Math.max(range1.getColumn(), range2.getColumn()),
    Math.min(range1.getLastRow(), range2.getLastRow()) - Math.max(range1.getRow(), range2.getRow()) + 1,
    Math.min(range1.getLastColumn(), range2.getLastColumn()) - Math.max(range1.getColumn(), range2.getColumn()) + 1,
  );

  return intersectRange;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to do exactly the same thing as you (see if the event.range belongs to one of the sheet's named ranges in an event handler), this is perfect.

Comment: Great answer, I'd add that you can extract variables for each to avoid calling the same function multiple times and speeding up execution, i.e. `var range2Col = range2.getColumn()`