# based on the edited cell how do I return the namedRange the cell belongs in?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function getNamedRange( e ) {
    const sheet       = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const activeRange = e.range;
    const namedRange  = sheet.getNamedRange( activeRange.getA1Notation() );

    //alert named range
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert( namedRange );

    return namedRange;
}
```

I have tried multiple ways of doing this to no avail.

Main goal: get the name of the named range where the edited cell is found

So if `A1:C5` was a named range of "firstRange"

and I edited cell `A2`, the `onEdit(e)` would run `getNamedRange(e)` and alert "firstRange"

I have tried `getName()` and all sorts of combos using the reference section

[Google Reference Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#getName())

Comment: The function name is wrong, it should be ```sheet.getNamedRanges()``` and that doesn't take any arguments. You should retrieve all named ranges using this function, then determine if the edited cell belongs to one of them. Tanaike has answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60981593/8282697

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically test if a Google Sheet cell is in a named range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975224/programmatically-test-if-a-google-sheet-cell-is-in-a-named-range)

Comment: You could use the new google apps script editor to avoid such syntax errors.

Comment: @Ninca Tirtil Thank you for checking it. First, when I saw this question and [https://stackoverflow.com/q/60975224](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60975224), also I thought that this might be the same situation. But, I noticed that in my answer, the intersection ranges between the specific range and the specific named range are retrieved. I thought that the basic method is the same. In order to use my answer for this question, it is required to modify a little. So, I proposed a modified script and a sample script as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when I saw this question and [Programmatically test if a Google Sheet cell is in a named range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60975224), also I thought that this might be the same situation. But, I noticed that in my answer, the intersection ranges between the specific range and the specific named range are retrieved. I thought that the basic method is the same. So in order to use my answer for this question, it is required to modify a little. So in this answer, I would like to propose the sample script for achieving the goal by modifying it.

#### Sample script 1:

When [this sample script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60981593) is modified for your script, it becomes as follows.

```js
function getNamedRange(e) {
  var inputRange = e.range;

  var columnToLetter = function (column) { // <--- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231012/7108653
    var temp, letter = '';
    while (column > 0) {
      temp = (column - 1) % 26;
      letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
      column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
    }
    return letter;
  };

  var res = [];
  var result = [];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var namedRanges = sheet.getNamedRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
    var nr = namedRanges[i];

    // Retrieve a1Notations from "inputRange".
    var iStartRow = inputRange.getRow();
    var iEndRow = iStartRow + inputRange.getNumRows() - 1;
    var iStartColumn = inputRange.getColumn();
    var iEndColumn = iStartColumn + inputRange.getNumColumns() - 1;
    var irA1Notations = [];
    for (var j = iStartRow; j <= iEndRow; j++) {
      var temp = [];
      for (var k = iStartColumn; k <= iEndColumn; k++) {
        temp.push(columnToLetter(k) + j);
      }
      Array.prototype.push.apply(irA1Notations, temp);
    }

    // Retrieve a1Notations from "myNamedRange".
    var namedRange = nr.getRange();
    var nStartRow = namedRange.getRow();
    var nEndRow = nStartRow + namedRange.getNumRows() - 1;
    var nStartColumn = namedRange.getColumn();
    var nEndColumn = nStartColumn + namedRange.getNumColumns() - 1;
    var nrA1Notations = {};
    for (var j = nStartRow; j <= nEndRow; j++) {
      for (var k = nStartColumn; k <= nEndColumn; k++) {
        nrA1Notations[columnToLetter(k) + j] = null;
      }
    }

    // Retrieve intersection ranges.
    result = irA1Notations.filter(function (e) { return nrA1Notations.hasOwnProperty(e) });
    if (result.length > 0) {
      res.push(nr.getName())
    }
  }
  if (res.length == 0) return;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(res.join(","));
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this case, I thought that the following simple script might be able to be used.

```js
function getNamedRange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const r = sheet.getNamedRanges().filter(r => {
    const temp = r.getRange();
    const startRow = temp.getRow();
    const endRow = startRow + temp.getNumRows();
    const startCol = temp.getColumn();
    const endCol = startCol + temp.getNumColumns();
    return (range.rowStart >= startRow && range.rowStart <= endRow && range.columnStart >= startCol && range.columnStart <= endCol) ? true : false;
  });
  if (r.length == 0) return;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(r.map(f => f.getName()).join(","));
}
```

#### Note:

- When you edit a cell, when the edited cell is included in the named range, a dialog is opened. And, you can see the name of the named range.
- From this question, it seems that you are using `getNamedRange` as the installable OnEdit trigger. In the above scripts, you can also use the simple trigger. So you can also modify the function name from `getNamedRange` to `onEdit`.
- In your script, `return namedRange;` is used. But when `getNamedRange` is run using the installable OnEdit trigger, I thought that `return namedRange;` is not used.

#### Reference:

- Related thread.

  - [Programmatically test if a Google Sheet cell is in a named range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60975224)

Comment: This answer worked perfectly. 

I didn't think about using intersection ranges to see where the updated cell was located. 

Thank you.

Comment: @Alex Howard Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.