# Is there really no build in method for converting notation to index "B3" to [2, 3]?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to refuse to believe that there is no Class Range method to retrieve the row or column index for a cell given. But I couldn't find anything searching for this other than the below-refered link.

```
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var cellPositionToConvert = activeSheet.getRange("B3")
// cellPositionToConvert ".GETCOLUMN()" ".GETROW()"
```

**Return I'm looking for:**

```
[2, 3]
```

I could only find this "famous" self-constructed function to deal with that.
I would be more than kneen to know and discuss, if there are any other ways to convert this a1Notation.

[stack overflow post-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229180/convert-column-index-into-corresponding-column-letter)

Comment: There is getRow() and getColumn()

Comment: @TheMaster `cellPositionToConvert.getColumn()` only returns `range` so nothing I can work with (like for example an int)

Comment: That would surprise me. `cellPositionToConvert.getColumn()` is expected to return correctly the column number as an int - provided `cellPositionToConvert` correctly contians an instance of a `range`.

Comment: You're completely right, I made the mistake somewhere else and ended up reading the wrong `Looger` data. I'll delete this post as my first try `.getColumn()` is now working correctly.

Comment: Should I delete the question or keep it? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

**Documentation** [Get Column](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn)

**Documentation** [Get Row](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)

```
// Get active Sheet
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

// Get cell by a1notation
var cellPositionToConvert = activeSheet.getRange("B3");

// Get row and column for choosen cell and store them in Array
var cellIndex = [activeSheet.getRow(), activeSheet.getColumn()];
```

Comment: Please add explanations and documentation links. Code only answers are frowned upon.