# Get values skip errors

Tags: google-apps-script

I‘m currently learning Google app scripts and encounter a small problem.

Background: I‘m fetching data from an API and write it into a spreadsheet, which is mostly working fine, and then do some work with the data.

In some cases the import is not working for what ever reason. (Cell value: #ERROR!)
For that cases I made a „copy“ function to copy the API data to another sheet,skipping errors. So if 1 import is broken I can work with the Last successfull one.

Problem:
For one sheet the runtime was too high so I changed from this code:

```
function copy() {
  var copyWert = ""; 
  for (var i = 3; i < 247; i++) { 
    for (var j = 1; j < 4;j++) {
      copyWert = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('API').getRange(i, j).getValue();
      if (copyWert == "#ERROR!" || copyWert == "" || copyWert == "#NAME!") {
        
      } else {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Copy').getRange(i, j).setValue(copyWert);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To:

```
function copy() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:D300").getValues();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Copy').getRange("A2:D300").setValues(values);
}
```

Which is way faster,but missing the check. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this:`function copy1() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('API');
  const rg=sh.getRange(3,1,245,4);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      if(vA[i][j]=="#ERROR" || vA[i][j]=="" || vA[i][j]=="#NAME") {
      }else{
        sh.getRange(i+3,j+1).setValue(vA[i][j])
      }
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the cell values from `API` to `Copy` when the value is not `"#ERROR!"`, `""` and `"#NAME!"`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

### Modification points:

- When you want to copy only the cell values which have no `"#ERROR!"`, `""` and `"#NAME!"`, in order to reduce the process cost, I would like to use Sheets API.

  - In this case, the cell values which have `"#ERROR!"`, `""` and `"#NAME!"` are not overwritten to the existing cells in `Copy`.
- When you can permit the overwrite the all cells, I think that your 2nd script might be used by modifying.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, when you want to copy only the cell values which have no `"#ERROR!"`, `""` and `"#NAME!"`, in order to reduce the process cost, I would like to use Sheets API.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function copy() {
  // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231012/7108653
  const columnToLetter = column => {
    let temp,
      letter = "";
    while (column > 0) {
      temp = (column - 1) % 26;
      letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
      column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
    }
    return letter;
  };
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var values = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API').getRange("A2:D300").getValues();
  var data = values.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
      r.forEach((copyWert, j) => {
        if (!(copyWert == "#ERROR!" || copyWert == "" || copyWert == "#NAME!")) {
          ar.push({range: `'Copy'!${columnToLetter(j + 1)}${i + 2}`, values: [[copyWert]]});
        }
      });
      return ar;
  }, []);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({data: data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"}, spreadsheet.getId());
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, your 2nd script is modified.

#### Sample script:

```
function copy() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var values = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API').getRange("A2:D300").getValues();
  values = values.map(r => r.map(copyWert => (copyWert == "#ERROR!" || copyWert == "" || copyWert == "#NAME!") ? "" : copyWert));
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy').getRange("A2:D300").setValues(values);
}
```

### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: In above scripts, please use the script with enabling V8 at the script editor.

Comment: I just realised, that this script work, but is replacing the error value with "" in the array. Which still overrides the old value in the Copy sheet.

Comment: @Dewx19 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I would like to confirm your current situation. 1. Which pattern are you using? 2. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Because in my environment, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike
I cant provide any sheet but can give you an example:
Api looks like
1123 test #ERROR! asdf
Copy looks like (before skript run):
1123 test asd asdf
Copy after skript run:
1123 test  asdf

Comment: @Dewx19 Thank you for replying. I could understand that you cannot provide the sample Spreadsheet. When you show the samples, please add them to your question by including more information. Because unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Api looks like 1123 test #ERROR! asdf Copy looks like (before skript run): 1123 test asd asdf Copy after skript run: 1123 test asdf`. I apologize for this. And, can I ask you about which pattern of my sample scripts you are using? Unfortunately, I'm not sure about the script you are using. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.