# Google App Script give multiple cellRange same conditional format based on 1 cell reference relative to each cellRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, v8, conditional-formatting

I'm writing a script that set conditional formatting for each group of cells, based on the 1st cell of each group.

```
For(i=0,i<10,i++)
/*
other part of the script
*/.whenFormulaSatisfied('=INDEX(A1)<0,5')
```

Instead of A1 I want to use a notation different than A1notation.
I need that A1 becomes after each loop C1, then E1, then G1 and so on.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can use [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation)

```
  for (var i = 0; i<10; i+=2){
    var cellNotation = sh.getRange(1,i+1).getA1Notation();
    console.log(cellNotation)
  }
```

Result

```
3:59:01 PM  Info    A1
3:59:01 PM  Info    C1
3:59:01 PM  Info    E1
3:59:01 PM  Info    G1
3:59:01 PM  Info    I1
```

Comment: This looks like easy to understand and implement, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode):

```
.whenFormulaSatisfied(`=INDEX(${String.fromCharCode(65+i)}1)<0,5`)
```

65 is the starting code for uppercase alphabets and codes for `A`. So this should work upto `Z`. If you need more than `Z`, See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229180/convert-column-index-into-corresponding-column-letter#comment79668919_45730487)

Comment: <p>Thanks for your answer!
I need more than `Z`. 
I find difficult to implement  in my code: 
`X=lambda n:~n and X(n/26-1)+chr(65+n%26)or'' ;`
I'm new to coding and I find difficult to get the meaning of this syntax and apply it correctly in my script code.
Anyway I understood the general meaning of your answer and the code to use for uppercase alphabet.</p>

Comment: @Bertocks There were plenty of other answers in that thread. Anyone of them would've worked.