# Specifying range until last column in Google AppScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have done a coding a Google AppScript but somehow it is not working. My coding is to specify until the the last column. I have attached the coding here. Can anyone help me with it?

```
  var lastRow = displaySheet.getLastColumn();
  var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange("G":lastRow).getValues();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From `getRange("G":lastRow)`, you want to retrieve the values from the column "G" to the last column for all rows of data range.

In this case, how about the following modification?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the method of `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` is used.

#### From:

```
var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange("G":lastRow).getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange(1, 7, displaySheet.getLastRow(), displaySheet.getLastColumn() - 6).getValues();
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, A1Notation is used.

#### Sample script:

```
// Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231012
const columnToLetter = column => {
  let temp,
    letter = "";
  while (column > 0) {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
};

var displaySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastColumn = displaySheet.getLastColumn();
var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange("G:" +  columnToLetter(lastColumn)).getValues();
```

- When you want to retrieve the value of data range, please modify the last line as follows.

  ```
    var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange(`G1:${columnToLetter(lastColumn)}${displaySheet.getLastRow()}`).getValues();
  ```

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)