# search for a specific Column and then lookup the value of the matching row based off a name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to get a google sheet to search for a specific cell in a table. The headers change so it might be A6 one week and then A9 the other and so on.

Once it's found that row, I want it to search and pull all of that departments names and data for the column its matched with.

I am 23  sheets in and my heads hit a brick wall and I just can figure it out.

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough details. How do we know which column header to look for?

Comment: Sorry, For example I would be looking for a count of a certain log. 

The logs are column headers, and the departments and individuals make up the rows

Comment: that still doesn't give clarity. Based on what you said, you can use `MATCH("certianlogName", logColumnHeaders, 0)`. But this info will most likely be insufficient for you. Please add some sample data to the question so that it can used as reference.

Comment: I've not explained it very well sorry, 
I have made this mock up to try and help it make sense. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uh7yg3X70UH2oT2Pm-0SbLZeIyMgA9ELEPQ8nhbv07Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've put an example on there as well of how it should return the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
=QUERY({A:B,INDEX(A:G,0,MATCH(D25,1:1,0))},"SELECT * WHERE Col2='" & LOWER(F25) & "'")
```

[image]

Note - you should remove unnecessary spaces. In sample data, they were in cells `C1` and `D25`.

Comment: I am getting this error message 
Error
Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1096. Actual: 1095.

Comment: =QUERY({Year!A2:A1097,Year!F3:F1097,INDEX(A:FT,0,match(C67,1:1,0))},"SELECT * WHERE Col 6 ='" & LOWER(B1) & "' ")

This is what I have entered

Comment: @AlasdairGrant As I said, you have trailing spaces in some cells. Check if they are also in the real data.

Comment: So this is an exact copy of how the spreadsheet looks. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1esXu94YYGorFBWUodlm5m4WDXYpkTLOr3WftgWhevx8/edit?usp=sharing

I can get it to work on the original example I shared but I cant get it to work on this.
I've checked for spaces.

Am I making a silly mistake somewhere?

Thankyou for your help I really apricate it

Comment: @AlasdairGrant For your dataset working formula will be: ```=QUERY({Data!A:F,index(Data!A:FT,0,MATCH(B2,Data!1:1,0))},"SELECT * WHERE Col6 ='" & A2 & "'")```

Comment: Okay! 

So, when I do that on the example sheet which matches the same format as the actual sheet it works perfectly! Thank you so much! 

However, when I put it in the real sheet I get this error 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j6ZsnAeNPVSaWbw9v6qF-mOlTOWbrF8g/view?usp=sharing

=QUERY({Year!A:F,index(Year!A:FT,0,MATCH(B67,Year!1:1,0))},"SELECT * WHERE Col6 ='" & B1 & "'")  Formula used

Comment: @AlasdairGrant This error means that ```INDEX``` / ```MATCH``` does not return the data you are looking for. Without seeing this data, I will not be able to give a reason. There it is necessary to check whether the ranges are correct, whether the search value in B67 corresponds to one of the names in the first row, or whether there is no space in the names in the first row or in search value.

Comment: You also can try to use ```TRIM``` function in the ```MATCH```: ```MATCH(TRIM(B67),TRIM(Year!1:1),0)```

Comment: Doh! I'd referenced the  the wrong cell! You're an absolute legend! It works now.

I really couldn't have done it without you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(
  FILTER(
    IFS(
      TRIM(1:20) = "", 0,
      ISNUMBER(1:20), 1:20,
      True, LOWER(TRIM(1:20))
    ),
    1:1 <> ""
  ),
  "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col" & MATCH(TRIM(D25), ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(1:1)),) & "
   WHERE Col2 = '" & LOWER(F25) & "'",
  1
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `CHAR(MATCH...))` and `Query` formula to get this

```
=QUERY('Sheet Name'!A1:G20,"SELECT A, B, "&CHAR(MATCH("Log 4",'Sheet Name'!A1:G1)+64)&" WHERE B='w'")
```

Above formula only works till column Z, but thanks to Kishkin's comment below, you can use it beyond Z like this:

```
=QUERY('Sheet Name'!A1:G20,"SELECT A, B, `" & =REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("Log 4",'Sheet Name'!A1:G1), 4), "\D+") & "` WHERE B='w'")
```

You use `SUBSTITUTE` instead of `REGEXTRACT` too. You can refer to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229180/convert-column-index-into-corresponding-column-letter).

- the CHAR(MATCH...)) gets the column name of the desired Log
- you can then use the column name to include that column in Query `select` statement

In the `MATCH` formula, you can also dynamically Match for a cell reference instead of specifying "Log 4" manually

**Note:** This is basically splitting the Query formula and concatenating it with another formula. So the `&`, `'` and `"` symbols are really important

Sample Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: Hope he won't need to return anything from column 77. :)

Comment: Good point kishkin, this only works till Column Z

Comment: Ah! right, there's `CHAR`. I was actually joking about `BY` column which breaks the query as it is a keyword.

Comment: You can replace `CHAR(N) + 64` with `REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(1, N, 4), "\D+")` to go beyond `Z`. But `BY` will still break it.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. And I had faced issue with column `BY` to, but you can work-around it by using backtick like this ` `BY` `

Comment: I still cant get it to to work. I am trying to do the query on a different sheet to the data is on. Would that affect the formula working?

Comment: Yes, that will affect the formula, you need to add references accordingly like `'SheetName'!A1:G20` and `'SheetName'!A1:G1`