# I am trying to sort a certain range on the basis of two variables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I have a table as shown above. I'm looking to sort the range `C386:D392` based on column D, whenever there's a edit in Column D.

`C386` comes from the top of the table.
`D392` comes from 386 to number of filled rows in column C. I already made a count of column C in B385.

I don't know why is not working.
The variable "cox" and "y" are my two variables to create the range I want to sort

```
function onEdit(e) {

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
   var d = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D:D').getColumn();
   var row = e.range.getRow();
   var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  
   if(col == d){
    var valor = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
    var x = sheet.getRange(row-valor,3).getRow();
    var cant = sheet.getRange(row-valor-1,2).getValue();
    var y = sheet.getRange(x+cant,4).getCell();
    var cox = sheet.getRange(x,col-1).getCell();
    spreadsheet.getRange(`${cox}:${y}`).activate()
    .sort({column: 4, ascending: true});
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the alert show? Your getCell is missing `()`

Comment: The alert don´t show anything, the problem is that the code no sort me the range.

Comment: I had copied the code wrong, in my code the get cell is right, I just fixed it.

Comment: In this `spreadsheet.getRange('cox:y').activate()` cox and y are no longer variables...they are just part of a string.  Perhaps you meant this `${cox}:${y}`

Comment: so I would have to express it like this? 

`spreadsheet.getRange(${cox}:${y}).activate()
 .sort({column: 4, ascending: true});`

Comment: now the alert show me that this line have a error :
`var col = e.range.getColumn();`

Comment: why this variable is incorrect?

Comment: getCell() requires two parameters

Comment: Your code really makes no sense I think it would be better to explain what you want to accomplish is words and picture because you code makes no sense at all.

Comment: I just upload a image, so my idea is: if someone change a number of the column D the range C386 until the column D and the row depending the amount of names of the column C, Which I Count with the function in B385, sort them in base to the column D . I hope you understand me @Cooper

Comment: How can someone change a number in column d of C386 since C386 is a cell in Column c.? I have no idea what you are taking about.  I am coming to think that your thinking is way beyond my ability to understand so I think I should move on and let someone more intelligent have an opportunity to assist you.

Comment: Although I understand, you really need to work on your communication skills. Punctuation, grammar are all important.

Comment: I am sorry I do not have a good level of English, my native language is Spanish. I will try to express myself as clearly as possible. 
I will express my idea again:
If someone change a number of the column D, the range "C386:D392" will sort by the Column D. This is the idea in simple words.
But the problem is that in the whole sheet are a lot of tables like this, which I want that they sort by them self and not write code in the function on `edit()` for each of this tables.
 @TheMaster @Cooper

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use template literals
- Hardcode `C` and `D`, if you're only using `C:D`
- Depending on usage, [`getDataRegion()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdataregion) may also help in your case.

```
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  if (col === 4) {
    const indexFromA = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
    const topRow = row - indexFromA;
    const countFromB = sheet.getRange(topRow - 1, 2).getValue();
    const bottomRow = topRow + countFromB;
    sheet.getRange(`C${topRow}:D${bottomRow}`).sort(4);
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally... Works!!!
Thank you so much for the solution and for putting up with me in spite of my poor English level
A last question, what I need to do if I want to put a variable in the values of  `c` and `d` in `sheet.getRange(`C${topRow}:D${bottomRow}`).sort(4);` because if you see my table have like anothers similar sections in where I need to do the same

Comment: @BenjaminUrrutia Could you ask a new question? With representative sample(Your current screenshot only shows 1 table). Where would be the count of E386:F{count}?  What if there are different number of names in column C and column D? Explain in detail in your new question. Also try to find the answer yourself, modify  your code, test it before posting a new question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Comment: @BenjaminUrrutia Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229180/convert-column-index-into-corresponding-column-letter) (especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158/))will help in your testing

Answer (score 1):

#### Template Literals

It hard to do in a comment.  But the inner expression in the range must surrounded by back ticks like this.

```
spreadsheet.getRange(`${cox}:${y}`).activate()  .sort({column: 4, ascending: true});
```

I believe these are called template literals and you can learn more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: I think it also should be `cox.getValue()` and `y.getValue()`, but not sure about those variables. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @TheMaster it could be but before it was written in A1Notation.  The whole script is  rather foolish and the entire onedit is very poorly organized there is virtually no control on unwanted triggers.

Comment: I invented a range to try if the code work, but i don´t why the part of getcell is giving me a mistake. so I Write the code of the following way and it´s work
`if(col == 4){
 var valor = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
 var x = sheet.getRange(row-valor,3).getRow();
 var cant = sheet.getRange(row-valor-1,2).getValue();
 var y = sheet.getRange(x+cant,4);
 var cox = sheet.getRange(x,col-1);
 spreadsheet.getRange('C386:D389').activate()
 .sort({column: 4, ascending: true});
 };
`

Comment: but if I don´t use the getcell I can´t give a reference to the next command to sort me the range with my variables