# How to retrieve data from specific column

Tags: google-apps-script

In my AppScript code, I've the below code, that returns perfectly columns `d` and `e` in a JSON format

```
fileID = "xxxxxxvxjRD_kjE7gzYE3WAcGdxaQEEQNReY"
sheetName = "Data"
function doGet(e) {
 // Logger.log(e.parameter.method);
   // Open Google Sheet using ID
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  // Read all data rows from Google Sheet
  const values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  // Converts data rows in json format
  const result = JSON.stringify(values.map(([a,b,c,d,e]) => ({SupplierName: d,Brand:e,})));
  // Returns Result
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

The `values.map(([a,b,c,d,e])` played important rule in the code above.

Now the numbers of column is increasing, and I need 2 columns, that are `z` and `ad` instead of `d` and `e`, do I need to include all the columns names in the array used in the `map` function, to be:

```js
values.map(([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t.....,ad])
```

Or there is abetter way to use the 2 indexes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following method?

#### Sample script:

```js
// Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231012
const letterToColumn = letter => {
  let column = 0,
    length = letter.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    column += (letter.charCodeAt(i) - 64) * Math.pow(26, length - i - 1);
  }
  return column;
};

const columnLetters = ["Z", "AD"]; // Column letters you want to retrieve.
const res = values.map(r => columnLetters.map(e => r[letterToColumn(e) - 1]));
console.log(res)
```

- In this sample script, in order to retrieve the values from the specific columns, the values are retrieved by converting the column letter to the column number. By this, you can retrieve the values by giving `const columnLetters = ["Z", "AD"]`.

Comment: It worked perfectly, but I did not understand the `length = letter.length;` line

Comment: @Hasan A Yousef Thank you for replying. About `length = letter.length`, this is used in the function `letterToColumn`. It seems that here, the length of the column letter is checked. For example, `AD` is 2. Using this, the column number is retrieved in the loop. This function is from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231012).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking what could be the meaning of letter length, it looks it is the number of letters in each column name, from "A" to "Z" it is 1, from "AA" to "ZZ" it is 2, from "AAA" to "ZZZ" it is 3, and so on.

Comment: @Hasan A Yousef Thank you for replying. Yes. I think that your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try get values by columns in this way:
Using Advance Sheets Services,`majorDimension: "COLUMNS",`
You can use get or batchGet method. Both works.

```
  const result ={}
  const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet('xxxxxxvxjRD_kjE7gzYE3WAcGdxaQEEQNReY', {
      ranges: [
        //provide the range your need eg from a to z
        "Data!A:Z",
      ],
      majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
    }).valueRanges;

  for ( i in values[0].values){
    //result[header[i]] = values[0].values[i]
     const header = values[0].values[i][0];
     result[header] = values[0].values[i]
  }

  console.log(result)
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```