# Is there a way to pull the Cell with the data for a range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get my data to return with the cell that its located in, currently I can get the data to pull back for the values in the range without the cell. Any help is really appreciated!

```
var rangeValues = worksheet.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();
console.log(rangeValues);
```

Currently Returns -
[ 'Becky', '$700' ],
[ 'John', '$600' ]

Trying to get -
[ 'A1', 'Becky', 'B1', '$700' ]
[ 'A2', 'John', 'B2', '$600' ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve `[ [ 'A1', 'Becky', 'B1', '$700' ], [ 'A2', 'John', 'B2', '$600' ] ]` from `var rangeValues = worksheet.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();`.

  - `rangeValues` is `[ [ 'Becky', '$700' ], [ 'John', '$600' ] ]`.

In order to achieve your goal, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
// Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231012
const columnToLetter = column => {
  let temp,
    letter = "";
  while (column > 0) {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
};

var worksheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set "worksheet".

var rangeValues = worksheet.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();
var res = rangeValues.map((r, i) => r.flatMap((c, j) => [columnToLetter(j + 1) + (i + 1), c]));
console.log(res);
```

- When this script is run, when `rangeValues` is `[ 'Becky', '$700' ], [ 'John', '$600' ]`, `[ [ 'A1', 'Becky', 'B1', '$700' ], [ 'A2', 'John', 'B2', '$600' ] ]` is obtained.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)