# google sheet script border by color

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to have borders on rows where the first cell of a row has a specific color.

I found this script, and tried modifying to to my needs.. but without success.

`function border1() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet1.getRange("A1:B50");
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var counter = 0;
  var gray = "#efefef";
  for (var i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++){
    if(backgrounds[i]== gray)
     //counter++;
      range.setBorder(true, false, true, true, true, true);      
  }
  Logger.log(counter);  
     //range.setBorder(true, false, true, true, true, true);  

}`

The problem is that when I run this, all my cells are borderd instead of the row with the specific color.
I think the command range.setborder has to refer to the cells with the background -->> (backgrounds[i]) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to apply the borders to the cells when the background color of column "A" is `var gray = "#efefef"`.

#### Modification points:

- From `The problem is that when I run this, all my cells are borderd instead of the row with the specific color.`, I thought that in your showing script, by `backgrounds[i]== gray`, no borders are written. Because `backgrounds` is 2-dimensional array. So, I'm worried that your showing script might be different from your tested script.
- And, even when `backgrounds[i]== gray` is modified to `backgrounds[i][0] == gray`, from `range.setBorder(true, false, true, true, true, true)`, in this case, the borders are written to all cells of `var range = sheet1.getRange("A1:B50")`. I thought that these are the reason for your current issue with your script.
- In your situation, RangeList might be able to be used for writing the borders.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function border1() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var colors = sheet1.getRange("A1:A" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getBackgrounds();
  var gray = "#efefef";
  var rangeList = colors.reduce((ar, [a], i) => {
    var row = i + 1;
    if (a == gray) ar.push(`A${row}:B${row}`);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sheet1.getRangeList(rangeList).setBorder(true, false, true, true, true, true);
}
```

- When this script is run, the background color of column "A" is checked, and when the background color is `#efefef`, the border is applied by `sheet1.getRangeList(rangeList).setBorder(true, false, true, true, true, true)`.
- In this modification, from your showing script, the borders are applied to the columns "A" and "B". If you want to set the borders to the whole row, please modify `A${row}:B${row}` to `A${row}:${row}`.
- If you want to apply the border to the data range, please modify the above script as follows.

  ```
    function border1() {
      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158
      const columnIndexToLetter_ = index =>
        (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter_(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : "";

      var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var colors = sheet1.getRange("A1:A" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getBackgrounds();
      var gray = "#efefef";
      var lastCol = columnIndexToLetter_(sheet1.getLastColumn() - 1);
      var rangeList = colors.reduce((ar, [a], i) => {
        var row = i + 1;
        if (a == gray) ar.push(`A${row}:${lastCol}${row}`);
        return ar;
      }, []);
      sheet1.getRangeList(rangeList).setBorder(true, false, true, true, true, true);
    }
  ```

#### Note:

- About the condition of border, in this modification, your showing condition of `true, false, true, true, true, true` is used. If you want to use other conditions, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))
- [setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal) of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal)

Comment: Thank you. So much to learn. I managed to modify your script to my needs. I added a check for white background, so the border is deleted when the color is removed.

Answer (score 2):

#### Set Border to solid red when color of first cell is yellow

```
function border1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const bgs = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getBackgrounds().flat();
  bgs.forEach((b, i) => {
    if (b == "#ffff00") {
      sh.getRange(i + 1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setBorder(true,true,true,true,false,false,"#ff0000",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
    }
  })
}
```