# Use Cell Range instead of A1-notation in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google API to fetch data from a Google Spreadsheet via Node.js.
In Excel VBA it is possible to either use

```
Range("A3") or Cells(3,1)
```

to reference the range of the cell.

And for a multiple cell range it would be like:

```
Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(2,3))
```

instead of:

```
Range("A1:C2")
```

I could not find out how to do that via the Google Sheets API.

Tried following this guideline, but I think it's not the thing I need here:
https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/articles/range-specification.html

My example code in Node.js looks like this:

```
async function getHelperData(cl){
    const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4', auth: cl});
    const opt = {
        spreadsheetId: gs.gs_ID,
        range: '_helperSheet!A1:C2'
    };

    let data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
    let dataArray = data.data.values;
    return dataArray;
};
```

Is it actually possible?

Answer (score 1):

About `Use Cell Range instead of A1-notation in Google Sheets` and the use of a value like `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(2,3))`, I thought that in the current stage, when Sheets API is used, the a1Notation is used for retrieving values from Google Spreadsheet. So, in this case, I thought that it is required to convert a value like `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(2,3))` to the a1Notation.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4', auth: cl});

const sheetName = "_helperSheet"; // Please set sheet name.
const rangeObj = { start: [1, 1], end: [2, 3] }; // This is from `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(2,3))` of "A1:C2" in your question.

const columnIndexToLetter_ = (index) => (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter_(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : ""; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158

const a1Notation = rangeObj.end ? `'${sheetName}'!${columnIndexToLetter_(rangeObj.start[1] - 1)}${rangeObj.start[0]}:${columnIndexToLetter_(rangeObj.end[1] - 1)}${rangeObj.end[0]}` : `'${sheetName}'!${columnIndexToLetter_(rangeObj.start[1] - 1)}${rangeObj.start[0]}`;
const opt = {
  spreadsheetId: gs.gs_ID,
  range: a1Notation,
};

let data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
let dataArray = data.data.values;
console.log(dataArray);
```

- In this modification, it supposes that the value of `gs.gs_ID` has already been declared elsewhere. Please be careful about this.
- In this modification, `a1Notation` returns `'_helperSheet'!A1:C2`.
- If `const rangeObj = { start: [1, 1] };` is used, `a1Notation` returns `'_helperSheet'!A1`.