# How to efficiently transfer data from multiple cells in one Google Sheet row to a template on another google sheet with different cell arrangement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, search, copy, data-transfer

I have a google sheet (named "Template") which I use to capture client data. Data entry cells in this "Template" sheet are not arranged in a sequential manner due to the way that the template is designed. I have a code to save this data to a second google sheet serving as my database( named "Data").  I am writing a code to search the saved client records from "Data"  by client unique identifier (client ID). After running the client record search function, I expect the data to be populated back to the original "Template". I can't seem to find **an efficient way** of achieving this using google apps script. The "Data" sheet will be having up to 50 columns of data per client.

Below is the code that I wrote. The code works as expected but I feel it's a long way of doing it and there might be a better and shorter way of achieving this when dealing with upwards of 50 columns per client. Is there a way to copy the entire row in "Data" sheet and paste the **respective** values to the range/array *(["D3", "B1", "B2", "E2", B4",...] as in example below)* in "Template" sheet using few lines of code, as opposed to setting value for each and every one of the 50 cells? Am still new to coding.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
templateS = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

//function to retrieve client record and populate template
function searchRecord() 

var searchCell = templateS.getRange("B6"); //cell holding the search value
var searchValue = searchCell.getValue(); // value to be used to search. Unique client ID. 


// Search record in data sheet using unique client ID
var recordFound = dataS.getRange("A:A") //client ID in column A of "Data"
                   .createTextFinder(searchValue) 
                   .matchCase(true)
                   .matchEntireCell(true)
                   .findNext();

var row = recordFound.getRow(); //capture row position containing the search value. 

//**populate template with up to 50 lines of below code**

templateS.getRange("D3").setValue(dataS.getRange(row, 1).getValue()); //capture client ID
templateS.getRange("B1").setValue(dataS.getRange(row, 2).getValue()); //capture title
templateS.getRange("B2").setValue(dataS.getRange(row, 3).getValue()); //capture surname
templateS.getRange("E2").setValue(dataS.getRange(row, 4).getValue()); //capture first name
templateS.getRange("B4").setValue(dataS.getRange(row, 5).getValue()); //capture address
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your showing script works fine.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your showing script.

In this case, how about using Sheets API? When Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) When Sheets API is used to your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

In this sample, I used `var dstRnages = ["D3", "B1", "B2", "E2", "B4"];` as the destination ranges. This is from your showing script. If you want to add more ranges, please modify it like `var dstRnages = ["D3", "B1", "B2", "E2", "B4", "##", "##",,,,];`. By this, the source ranges are automatically created by `var srcRanges = [...Array(dstRnages.length)].map((_, i) => (`'Data'!${columnIndexToLetter_(i)}${row}`));`. If you want to change this, please modify this.

```js
function searchRecord() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateS = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var searchCell = templateS.getRange("B6");
  var searchValue = searchCell.getValue();
  var recordFound = dataS.getRange("A:A")
    .createTextFinder(searchValue)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findNext();

  // I modified the below script.
  if (!recordFound) return;
  var dstRnages = ["D3", "B1", "B2", "E2", "B4"]; // This is from your script.

  // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158
  const columnIndexToLetter_ = index => (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter_(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : "";

  var row = recordFound.getRow();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  dstRanges = dstRnages.map(e => `'Template'!${e}`);
  var srcRanges = [...Array(dstRnages.length)].map((_, i) => (`'Data'!${columnIndexToLetter_(i)}${row}`));
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: srcRanges }).valueRanges.map(({ values }, i) => ({ values, range: dstRanges[i] }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from `srcRanges`, and the retrieved values are put to `dstRanges`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your showing script works fine. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: The solution you offered worked well. I just followed it as is. Many thanks. My issue now is understanding in simple terms the last 3 lines in the modified code to help me in future coding and modifying code if need be. Will read through the references you posted. Once again thank you.