# How To Set A1notation For All Row (Just Set Column Initial)

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I want to Set Formula for some cell, depend on how much data I have.
The problem was, I can't write script to make Range without Row Initial ( e.g Range(A:AA)).
To make just Column Initial, I try to replace Parameter : lastCol and lastRow with blank string ('') , and Zero Number (0), but not work.
Thanks

```
function recap() {

var   sheet             =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var   sheetForm         =   sheet.getSheetByName('METER')
const sheetPrint        =   sheet.getSheetByName('CETAK TAGIHAN')
const n                 =   5
var   lastRow           =   sheetForm.getLastRow()
var   lastCol           =   n+4
const startRow          =   7 
const currentCol        =   3 

for (let i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
```

// FORMULA =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,5)

// HOW TO SET ALL COLUMN RANGE :(A:I)  WITHOUT ROW NUMBER

```
sheetPrint.getRange(i+startRow,currentCol).setFormula('vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!'+sheetForm.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastCol).getA1Notation()+','+(5+i)+')');

}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the sample formulas you want to put to the cells "C7:C11"? I guessed "C7:C11" from your script."C7:C11".

Comment: Sample Formula from "C7 : C11"
=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A1:I101,5)
=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A1:I101,6)
=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A1:I101,7)
=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A1:I101,8)
=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A1:I101,9)

Comment: I want the Formula from "C7 : C11",  be like : 
=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,5) =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,6) =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,7) =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,8) =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,9)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `A:I` of `=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,5)`, in this case, you are required to receive the last column from "METER" sheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, 
If the Row Number added in the Range Initial, for now The formula  work. If I use the existing Last Row for Now, Its Just 100 Row (default New Sheet Row). So the Formula will be  "METER!A1:I100,5" , in the future when the row more than 100, the formula will did not work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function recap() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetForm = sheet.getSheetByName('METER')
  const sheetPrint = sheet.getSheetByName('CETAK TAGIHAN')
  const n = 5

  const lastColumn = sheetForm.getLastColumn();
  const columnIndexToLetter_ = index => (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter_(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : ""; // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158
  const columnLetter = columnIndexToLetter_(lastColumn - 1);
  const formulas = [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => [`=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:${columnLetter},${i + 5})`]);
  sheetPrint.getRange(7, 3, formulas.length).setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

- When this script is run, the following formulas are put to the cells "C7:C11".

  ```
    =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,5)
    =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,6)
    =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,7)
    =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,8)
    =vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,9)
  ```
- If the value of `METER!A:I` is constant, I think that the following modification might be able to be used.

  ```js
  function recap() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheetForm = sheet.getSheetByName('METER')
    const sheetPrint = sheet.getSheetByName('CETAK TAGIHAN')
    const n = 5
    const formulas = [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => [`=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!A:I,${i + 5})`]);
    sheetPrint.getRange(7, 3, formulas.length).setFormulas(formulas);
  }
  ```
- As another approach, the following modified script might be able to be used. In this case, the number values are removed from a1Notation.

  ```js
  function recap() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheetForm = sheet.getSheetByName('METER')
    const sheetPrint = sheet.getSheetByName('CETAK TAGIHAN')
    const n = 5
    const a1Notation = sheetForm.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheetForm.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation().replace(/\d/g, "");
    const formulas = [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => [`=vlookup((max(METER!A:A)),METER!${a1Notation},${i + 5})`]);
    sheetPrint.getRange(7, 3, formulas.length).setFormulas(formulas);
  }
  ```

#### Note:

- I think that when the formulas are put using `setFormulas`, the process cost can be reduced a little.

Comment: Wow.
It's  done !
Thanks @Tanaike  for your kindly,  to  help me  fix this.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: The value of METER!A:I  not constant.
So I  used your previous script.
Thanks

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for the additional information.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike
Sorry, because your previous script was work,  I don't read your  last script here.
It's right, the last script more simple and reduce process. 
As a new learner, It's helpfull  and I can use that script on another case in my project.