# Send email per column if specific data in row cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script on my [example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DVboM53aDVsXZfXRBdVPCutzsSscY51d_TBDUFNdi_c/edit?usp=sharing), which, on a spreadsheet edit, will send an email containing the data in the applicable column cells of Rows 2 and 3 whenever a cell in Row 7 has the words 'Send email' added to it, which will then add 'Email sent' to the same cell.

For example, if I choose 'Send email' in Cell E7, the email should immediately send, with a message to the extent of "Your data is 'Cell E2' and 'Cell E3'", and then Cell E7 should change to 'Email sent'.

[image]

I've had some success with doing this for rows, so I've tried to tweak my script to work for columns, but I have not yet been successful. This is my current script:

```
var EmailSent = 'Email sent';

    function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet9');
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = dataRange.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, lastCol);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var col = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "fake@email.com";
    var message = "Email details here." + row[-1] + row[-1] ;
    var emailSent = col[6];;
    if (emailSent == "Send email") {
      var subject = 'Message from Sheet9.';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startCol + i, 7).setValue(EmailSent);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

How would I best accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When you run the script, you want to send emails by checking row 7.
- When the email is sent, you want to include the values from rows 2 and 3 for each column.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var EmailSent = 'Email sent';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet9');
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = dataRange.getLastColumn();

  // I modified the below script.
  const columnIndexToLetter_ = index => (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter_(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : ""; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastCol).getDisplayValues();
  var [, ...tValues] = data[0].map((_, c) => data.map(r => r[c]));
  var ranges = tValues.reduce((ar, c, i) => {
    if (c[5] == "Send email") {
      var emailAddress = "fake@email.com";
      var subject = 'Message from Sheet9.';
      var message = `Your data is '${c[0]}' and '${c[1]}'`; // or var message = "Email details here." + c[0] + c[1]; of your current script.
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      ar.push(`${columnIndexToLetter_(i + 1)}7`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(EmailSent);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are checked in every column. And, when row 7 is "Send email", an email is sent by including the values of rows 2 and 3. And, row 7 is modified to "Email sent".

#### Note:

- This modified script is for your provided Spreadsheet. If you change the Spreadsheet, this modified script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Added:

About your following new question,

> Using this method, if I add Sheet10 to list names in column A with corresponding email addresses in Column B, and would like variable emailAddress to be determined based on the name in Row 6 of Sheet9, would you have a suggestion on how to best accomplish this?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var EmailSent = 'Email sent';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet10 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet10");
  var obj = sheet10.getRange("A2:B" + sheet10.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((o, [a, b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {});
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet9');
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = dataRange.getLastColumn();
  const columnIndexToLetter_ = index => (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter_(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : ""; // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastCol).getDisplayValues();
  var [, ...tValues] = data[0].map((_, c) => data.map(r => r[c]));
  var ranges = tValues.reduce((ar, c, i) => {
    if (c[5] == "Send email") {
      var emailAddress = obj[c[4]];
      if (emailAddress) {
        var subject = 'Issue Assignment';
        var message = `Please investigate ${c[0]}: ${c[1]} and solve.`; // or var message = "Email details here." + c[0] + c[1]; of your current script.
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        ar.push(`${columnIndexToLetter_(i + 1)}7`);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Email address was not found.");
      }
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(EmailSent);
}
```

- When this script is run, the above goal is achieved.

#### Note:

- This modified script is for your provided Spreadsheet. If you change the Spreadsheet, this modified script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: This is exactly what I was attempting to accomplish, thank you! Using this method, if I add Sheet10 to list names in column A with corresponding email addresses in Column B, and would like variable emailAddress to be determined based on the name in Row 6 of Sheet9, would you have a suggestion on how to best accomplish this? I've updated my example sheet, let me know if this requires posting a new question.

Comment: @J. Kubassek About your new question, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: It works exactly as required. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @J. Kubassek Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad both questions were resolved. Thank you, too.