# Ways to speed up a script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to speed up this script as it is taking 1 minute and 40 seconds to run.  It works properly but is there a way to speed it up using another method to achieve the same.
It takes all the data from the cells of a Userform and inserts them into an already existing row in a Database.

```
//function to edit the record

function updateRecord(){

  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Userform");
  var datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Database");
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response=ui.alert("Edit", 'Do you want to UPDATE the Record?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if(response==ui.Button.NO){

    return; // exit from this function

  }

  var str=shUserForm.getRange("B4").getValue(); //Getting the Customer Name 

  var values=datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var valuesFound=false;

  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){

    var rowValue=values[i];

    if(rowValue[0]==str){

      var iRow=i+1;


datasheet.getRange(iRow,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B5").getValue()); //INVOICE NUMBER
datasheet.getRange(iRow,3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B6").getValue()); //ADDRESS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B7").getValue()); //POST CODE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B8").getValue()); //TEL NO 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B9").getValue()); //TEL NO 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D5").getValue()); //MEASURING DATE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D6").getValue()); //MEASURING TIME
datasheet.getRange(iRow,9).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D7").getValue()); //ROOMS TO BE MEASURED
datasheet.getRange(iRow,10).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D8").getValue()); //OTHER INSTRUCTIONS


datasheet.getRange(iRow,11).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A12").getValue()); //FITTING 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,12).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A13").getValue()); //FITTING 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,13).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A14").getValue()); //FITTING 3
datasheet.getRange(iRow,14).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B12").getValue()); //FITTER 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,15).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B13").getValue()); //FITTER 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,16).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B14").getValue()); //FITTER 3

SpreadsheetApp.flush()

//CARPET PRODUCTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,17).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A18").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,18).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B18").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,19).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C18").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,20).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D18").getValue()); //UNDERLAY
datasheet.getRange(iRow,21).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E18").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,22).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G18").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,23).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A19").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,24).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B19").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,25).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C19").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,26).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D19").getValue()); //UNDERLAY
datasheet.getRange(iRow,27).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E19").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,28).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G19").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,29).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A20").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,30).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B20").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,31).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C20").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,32).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D20").getValue()); //UNDERLAY
datasheet.getRange(iRow,33).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E20").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,34).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G20").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,35).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A21").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,36).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B21").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,37).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C21").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,38).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D21").getValue()); //UNDERLAY
datasheet.getRange(iRow,39).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E21").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,40).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G21").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,41).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A22").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,42).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B22").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,43).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C22").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,44).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D22").getValue()); //UNDERLAY
datasheet.getRange(iRow,45).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E22").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,46).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G22").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,47).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A23").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,48).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B23").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,49).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C23").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,50).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D23").getValue()); //UNDERLAY
datasheet.getRange(iRow,51).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E23").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,52).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G23").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,53).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A24").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,54).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B24").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,55).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C24").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,56).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D24").getValue()); //UNDERLAY
datasheet.getRange(iRow,57).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E24").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,58).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G24").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,59).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A25").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,60).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B25").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,61).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C25").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,62).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D25").getValue()); //UNDERLAY
datasheet.getRange(iRow,63).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E25").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,64).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G25").getValue()); //SIZE 2

SpreadsheetApp.flush()

//HARD FLOORING PRODUCTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,65).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A29").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,66).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B29").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,67).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C29").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,68).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D29").getValue()); //PRODUCT COST
datasheet.getRange(iRow,69).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E29").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,70).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G29").getValue()); //SIZE 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,71).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I29").getValue()); //PACK SIZE

datasheet.getRange(iRow,72).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A30").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,73).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B30").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,74).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C30").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,75).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D30").getValue()); //PRODUCT COST
datasheet.getRange(iRow,76).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E30").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,77).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G30").getValue()); //SIZE 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,78).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I30").getValue()); //PACK SIZE

datasheet.getRange(iRow,79).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A31").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,80).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B31").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,81).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C31").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,82).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D31").getValue()); //PRODUCT COST
datasheet.getRange(iRow,83).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E31").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,84).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G31").getValue()); //SIZE 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,85).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I31").getValue()); //PACK SIZE

datasheet.getRange(iRow,86).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A32").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,87).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B32").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,88).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C32").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,89).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D32").getValue()); //PRODUCT COST
datasheet.getRange(iRow,90).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E32").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,91).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G32").getValue()); //SIZE 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,92).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I32").getValue()); //PACK SIZE

datasheet.getRange(iRow,93).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A33").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,94).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B33").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,95).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C33").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,96).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D33").getValue()); //PRODUCT COST
datasheet.getRange(iRow,97).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E33").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,98).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G33").getValue()); //SIZE 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,99).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I33").getValue()); //PACK SIZE

datasheet.getRange(iRow,100).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A34").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,101).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B34").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,102).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C34").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,103).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D34").getValue()); //PRODUCT COST
datasheet.getRange(iRow,104).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E34").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,105).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G34").getValue()); //SIZE 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,106).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I34").getValue()); //PACK SIZE

datasheet.getRange(iRow,107).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A35").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,108).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B35").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,109).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C35").getValue()); //RANGE & COLOUR
datasheet.getRange(iRow,110).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D35").getValue()); //PRODUCT COST
datasheet.getRange(iRow,111).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E35").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,112).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G35").getValue()); //SIZE 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,113).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I35").getValue()); //PACK SIZE

SpreadsheetApp.flush()

//VINYLS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,114).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A39").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,115).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B39").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,116).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C39").getValue()); //COLOUR & DESIGN

datasheet.getRange(iRow,118).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E39").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,119).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G39").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,120).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A40").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,121).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B40").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,122).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C40").getValue()); //COLOUR & DESIGN

datasheet.getRange(iRow,124).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E40").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,125).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G40").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,126).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A41").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,127).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B41").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,128).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C41").getValue()); //COLOUR & DESIGN

datasheet.getRange(iRow,130).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E41").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,131).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G41").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,132).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A42").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,133).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B42").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,134).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C42").getValue()); //COLOUR & DESIGN

datasheet.getRange(iRow,136).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E42").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,137).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G42").getValue()); //SIZE 2

datasheet.getRange(iRow,138).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A43").getValue()); //ROOM
datasheet.getRange(iRow,139).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B43").getValue()); //PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,140).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C43").getValue()); //COLOUR & DESIGN

datasheet.getRange(iRow,142).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E43").getValue()); //SIZE 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,143).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G43").getValue()); //SIZE 2

SpreadsheetApp.flush()

//SCREEDS ETC
datasheet.getRange(iRow,144).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A47").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,145).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B47").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,146).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D47").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,147).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H47").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,148).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I47").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

datasheet.getRange(iRow,149).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A48").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,150).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B48").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,151).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D48").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,152).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H48").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,153).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I48").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

datasheet.getRange(iRow,154).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A49").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,155).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B49").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,156).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D49").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,157).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H49").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,158).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I49").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

datasheet.getRange(iRow,159).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A50").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,160).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B50").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,161).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D50").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,162).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H50").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,163).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I50").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

datasheet.getRange(iRow,164).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A51").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,165).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B51").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,166).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D51").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,167).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H51").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,168).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I51").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

datasheet.getRange(iRow,169).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A52").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,170).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B52").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,171).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D52").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,172).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H52").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,173).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I52").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

datasheet.getRange(iRow,174).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A53").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,175).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B53").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,176).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D53").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,177).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H53").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,178).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I53").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

datasheet.getRange(iRow,179).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A54").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,180).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B54").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,181).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D54").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,182).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H54").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,183).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I54").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

datasheet.getRange(iRow,184).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A55").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,185).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B55").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,186).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D55").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,187).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H55").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,188).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I55").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

datasheet.getRange(iRow,189).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A56").getValue()); //SCREED PRODUCT
datasheet.getRange(iRow,190).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B56").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,191).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D56").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,192).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H56").getValue()); //COSUMABLES
datasheet.getRange(iRow,193).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I56").getValue()); //NUMBER REQUIRED

SpreadsheetApp.flush()

//UPLIFT & DISPOSAL

datasheet.getRange(iRow,194).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("N54").getValue()); //METREAGE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,195).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("N55").getValue()); //FITTING COSTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,196).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("N56").getValue()); //COSUMABLES

//FURTHER INFORMATION
datasheet.getRange(iRow,197).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A67").getValue()); //INFORMATION 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,198).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A69").getValue()); //INFORMATION 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,199).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A71").getValue()); //INFORMATION 3

//ORDER TYPE & DATE OF ORDER
datasheet.getRange(iRow,201).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I74").getValue()); //ORDER TYPE
datasheet.getRange(iRow,202).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("M74").getValue()); //DATE OF ORDER

//COST ADJUSTMENTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,203).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("J68").getValue()); //FITTING COST ADJUSTMENTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,204).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H69").getValue()); //COST ADJUSTMENT 1 REASON
datasheet.getRange(iRow,205).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("J69").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,206).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H70").getValue()); //COST ADJUSTMENT 2 REASON
datasheet.getRange(iRow,207).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("J70").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,208).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("H71").getValue()); //COST ADJUSTMENT 3 REASON
datasheet.getRange(iRow,209).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("J71").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 3

//MIESCELLANEOUS ADDITIONS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,210).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A60").getValue()); //FITTING COST ADJUSTMENTS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,211).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C60").getValue()); //COST ADJUSTMENT 1 REASON
datasheet.getRange(iRow,212).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A61").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 1
datasheet.getRange(iRow,213).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C61").getValue()); //COST ADJUSTMENT 2 REASON
datasheet.getRange(iRow,214).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A62").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,215).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C62").getValue()); //COST ADJUSTMENT 3 REASON
datasheet.getRange(iRow,216).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A64").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 3
datasheet.getRange(iRow,217).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C64").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,218).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A65").getValue()); //COST ADJUSTMENT 3 REASON
datasheet.getRange(iRow,219).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C65").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 3

//PAYMENT OPTIONS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,220).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A75").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 2
datasheet.getRange(iRow,221).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B75").getValue()); //COST ADJUSTMENT 3 REASON
datasheet.getRange(iRow,222).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C75").getValue()); //ADJUSTMENT AMOUNT 3

//EXTRA CARPET ROWS
datasheet.getRange(iRow,223).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A17").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,224).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B17").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,225).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C17").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,226).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D17").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,227).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E17").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,228).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G17").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,229).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("A26").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,230).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B26").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,231).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C26").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,232).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D26").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,233).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E26").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,234).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G26").getValue()); 

datasheet.getRange(iRow,235).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("I75").getValue()); 
datasheet.getRange(iRow,236).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("N1").getValue()); 

    ui.alert("Data updated!");   
  

    valuesFound=true;

    return;

  }

  }


if(valuesFound==false){

  ui.alert("No Record Found!");


}
```

I have tried to use a batch update, which I found on this site but it keeps failing.
Any suggestions please and I will research them.

Comment: The short answer is to organize the data in your form so that read it all with getValues() and do all of your work with arrays and write it all  back with setValues().  If you do that then your code will run ten times faster.  As for modifying your current script I'd say go back the the drawing board and rethink the entire design to make it easy for the programmer.

Comment: - [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your showing script works fine.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your showing script.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, Sheets API is used. I thought that when the values are efficiently got and put for the scattered cells, Sheets API might be useful.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function updateRecord() {
  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Userform");
  var datasheet = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Database");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert("Edit", 'Do you want to UPDATE the Record?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) {
    return; // exit from this function
  }
  var str = shUserForm.getRange("B4").getValue(); //Getting the Customer Name


  // I modified the below script.
  var search = datasheet.getRange("A1:A" + datasheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(str).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (search) {
    var ssId = myGoogleSheet.getId();
    var targetRow = search.getRow();
    var srcRangesA1Notation = ["B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "A12", "A13", "A14", "B12", "B13", "B14", "A18", "B18", "C18", "D18", "E18", "G18", "A19", "B19", "C19", "D19", "E19", "G19", "A20", "B20", "C20", "D20", "E20", "G20", "A21", "B21", "C21", "D21", "E21", "G21", "A22", "B22", "C22", "D22", "E22", "G22", "A23", "B23", "C23", "D23", "E23", "G23", "A24", "B24", "C24", "D24", "E24", "G24", "A25", "B25", "C25", "D25", "E25", "G25", "A29", "B29", "C29", "D29", "E29", "G29", "I29", "A30", "B30", "C30", "D30", "E30", "G30", "I30", "A31", "B31", "C31", "D31", "E31", "G31", "I31", "A32", "B32", "C32", "D32", "E32", "G32", "I32", "A33", "B33", "C33", "D33", "E33", "G33", "I33", "A34", "B34", "C34", "D34", "E34", "G34", "I34", "A35", "B35", "C35", "D35", "E35", "G35", "I35", "A39", "B39", "C39", "E39", "G39", "A40", "B40", "C40", "E40", "G40", "A41", "B41", "C41", "E41", "G41", "A42", "B42", "C42", "E42", "G42", "A43", "B43", "C43", "E43", "G43", "A47", "B47", "D47", "H47", "I47", "A48", "B48", "D48", "H48", "I48", "A49", "B49", "D49", "H49", "I49", "A50", "B50", "D50", "H50", "I50", "A51", "B51", "D51", "H51", "I51", "A52", "B52", "D52", "H52", "I52", "A53", "B53", "D53", "H53", "I53", "A54", "B54", "D54", "H54", "I54", "A55", "B55", "D55", "H55", "I55", "A56", "B56", "D56", "H56", "I56", "N54", "N55", "N56", "A67", "A69", "A71", "I74", "M74", "J68", "H69", "J69", "H70", "J70", "H71", "J71", "A60", "C60", "A61", "C61", "A62", "C62", "A64", "C64", "A65", "C65", "A75", "B75", "C75", "A17", "B17", "C17", "D17", "E17", "G17", "A26", "B26", "C26", "D26", "E26", "G26", "I75", "N1"];
    var dstColumns = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236];
    var maxCol = datasheet.getMaxColumns();
    if (maxCol < 236) {
      datasheet.insertColumns(maxCol, 236 - maxCol);
    }
    var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: srcRangesA1Notation.map(e => `'Userform'!${e}`) }).valueRanges;
    var columnIndexToLetter_ = index => (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter_(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : ""; // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158
    var data = dstColumns.map((e, i) => ({ range: `'Database'!${columnIndexToLetter_(e - 1)}${targetRow}`, values: values[i].values }));
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);
    ui.alert("Data updated!");
  } else {
    ui.alert("No Record Found!");
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, the values are retrieved with "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet". And, the retrieved values are put with "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate".
- When I tested this modified script, the process time was about 5 seconds.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: @Tanaika, when I saw this I thought “ya just organize the gets and sets into contiguous regions” but then I said to myself “why?”. You have more patience then me.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you for your comment. I also thought of the same situation when I saw this question for the first time. But, when I tested OP's script, I noticed that the cells of the source values were not continuous. So, I suggested using Sheets API. As additional information, when the script is tested with a sample sheet created with the cells including the values of A1Notations, it helps to understand the situation. From this sample sheet, I automatically created the values of `srcRangesA1Notation` and `dstColumns` in my script using a script.

Comment: The time to rearrange the whole form has well passed as it is already in use and is already feeding data to an Appsheet App although if I cannot get it to speed up then I will have to consider taking that course of action.  All works well save for this one script.  I have tried the modified script and it runs but it doesn't update the data.  I have the Google Sheets API service installed. I have spent a couple of hours trying to understand how the modified script should work and why it isn't working on my sheets. I have though been unsucessful.

Comment: @Graham Tomlinson Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I have tried the modified script and it runs but it doesn't update the data.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual Spreadsheet. So, by guessing your Spreadsheet, I prepared my modified script. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Graham Tomlinson In the current stage, I think that it is required to correctly replicate your situation. So, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? At that time, please include your current script. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike - no need to apologise as one of your scripts enabled me to speed up the input of the data in the first instance.  Once I have stripped out a lot of personal details I will provide a sample spreadsheet for you to look at.  If I can figure out how to give you access to it.

Comment: @Graham Tomlinson Thank you for replying. About `Once I have stripped out a lot of personal details I will provide a sample spreadsheet for you to look at.`, I would like to wait for it.

Comment: @Tanaike I have managed to sort the issue. Because the Userform held all the data which included the new data needing to be updated, I used a script to delete the original record and insert the details afresh using a script you had previously posted on this site. Thx for your time.

Comment: @Graham Tomlinson Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I have managed to sort the issue. Because the Userform held all the data which included the new data needing to be updated, I used a script to delete the original record and insert the details afresh using a script you had previously posted on this site. Thx for your time.`. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: The Userform is completed by the User and Script 1 (Insert) transfers the Data to the Database.  When I want to add/alter the data for a particular record Script 2 (Get Record) pulls the data from the Database back to the Userform.  The Userform is updated by the User.  Script 3 (Update Record) now performs 2 functions - it first deletes the original record from the Database and then using Script 1 inserts a new Record into the Database from the Userform. It works very well and completes in less than 5 seconds.

Comment: @Graham Tomlinson Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.