# Convert 2D array indices to spreadsheet cell co-ordinates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Pretty self-explanatory, but given 2D array indices (as CSV), how do I convert it to a spreadsheet cell coordinates? For example, `"0, 0"` would output `"A1"`, `"3, 4"` would be `"D5"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split and convert strings to number and  use `String.fromCodePoint`:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const csv = "2, 1";
const parseIndicesToA1 = str => str.split(", ").map(Number).reduce((a,c)=>String.fromCodePoint(65+a)+(c+1));
console.log(parseIndicesToA1(csv))
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

For >=26, see
[Convert column index into corresponding column letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229180/convert-column-index-into-corresponding-column-letter)

Answer (score 1):

### SUGGESTION:

**Try this:**

```
function myFunction() {

  var sample = [[0,0],[3,4]]; //your sample 2d array
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sample.forEach(x => console.log(sheet.getRange(x[1] + 1, x[0] +1).getA1Notation()) ) 

}
```

**Log results:**

[image]

**Reference:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation