# Google apprscript to copy specific rows from specific sheets to a new spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create an appscript to copy specific rows from specific sheets to a new spreadsheet.
I was able to get this script, but facingi

```
function copySpecificData() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = "source_spreadsheet";
  var sourceSpreadsheet;
  var sourceSpreadsheetFile;
  
  const files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('source_spreadsheet');

if (files.hasNext()) {
  const fileId = files.next().getId();

  console.log(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getName());
  sourceSpreadsheetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
}

  var destinationSpreadsheetFile = SpreadsheetApp.create("dest_spreadsheet");
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = destinationSpreadsheetFile.getId();
  
  var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);

 var sheetsToCopy = [
    { name: "README"},
    { name: "TEST", columns: ["A", "B", "E", "F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T"] },
    { name: "EXAMPLE", columns: ["A", "B", "E", "F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T"] },
    { name: "TEXT", columns: ["A", "B", "E", "F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T"] }
   
  ];


  sheetsToCopy.forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet.name);
    var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
    destinationSheet.setName(sheet.name);

    sheet.columns.forEach(function(column, index) {
      var range = sourceSheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);
      range.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(1, index + 1), { contentsOnly: true });
    });
  });

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("New spreadsheet created " + destinationSpreadsheet.getUrl());
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error   
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:35
copySpecificData    @ Code.gs:30
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share a sample sheet with your data and desired output. remove sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, the 1st element of `sheetsToCopy` has no property of `columns`. I guess that this might be the reason for your current issue of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')`.
- When this issue was removed, I'm worried that an error occurred at `range.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(1, index + 1), { contentsOnly: true });`. Because in the current stage, `copyTo` of Class Range cannot be used for the different Spreadsheets. I guessed that this might be the 2nd issue.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet.columns.forEach(function(column, index) {
  var range = sourceSheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);
  range.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(1, index + 1), { contentsOnly: true });
});
```

#### To:

```
if (!sheet.columns) return;
sheet.columns.forEach(function (column, index) {
  var range = sourceSheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);
  var values = range.getValues();
  destinationSheet.getRange(1, index + 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
});
```

As another approach, if your sheet has a lot of rows, how about using Sheets API? When Sheets API is used, the above modification is as follows. When Sheets API is used, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). In this modification, it processes every sheet.

#### From:

```
sheetsToCopy.forEach(function(sheet) {
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet.name);
  var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
  destinationSheet.setName(sheet.name);

  sheet.columns.forEach(function(column, index) {
    var range = sourceSheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);
    range.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(1, index + 1), { contentsOnly: true });
  });
});
```

#### To:

```
var columnIndexToLetter = index => (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : ""; // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158
var data = sheetsToCopy.flatMap(sheet => {
  var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
  destinationSheet.setName(sheet.name);
  if (!sheet.columns) return [];
  return Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(sourceSpreadsheet.getId(), { ranges: sheet.columns.map(e => `'${sheet.name}'!${e}1:${e}`) }).valueRanges.map(({ values }, i) => ({ values, range: `'${sheet.name}'!${columnIndexToLetter(i)}1` }));
});
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, destinationSpreadsheet.getId());
```

#### Note:

The modified whole script is as follows.

```js
function copySpecificData() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = "source_spreadsheet";
  var sourceSpreadsheet;
  var sourceSpreadsheetFile;
  const files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('source_spreadsheet');
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    const fileId = files.next().getId();
    console.log(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getName());
    sourceSpreadsheetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  }
  var destinationSpreadsheetFile = SpreadsheetApp.create("dest_spreadsheet");
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = destinationSpreadsheetFile.getId();
  var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
  var sheetsToCopy = [
    { name: "README" },
    { name: "TEST", columns: ["A", "B", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"] },
    { name: "EXAMPLE", columns: ["A", "B", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"] },
    { name: "TEXT", columns: ["A", "B", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"] }

  ];
  sheetsToCopy.forEach(function (sheet) {
    var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet.name);
    var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
    destinationSheet.setName(sheet.name);
    if (!sheet.columns) return;
    sheet.columns.forEach(function (column, index) {
      var range = sourceSheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);
      var values = range.getValues();
      destinationSheet.getRange(1, index + 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    });
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("New spreadsheet created " + destinationSpreadsheet.getUrl());
}
```

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))

Comment: Thank you. I was able to copy the sheets. I see the values are being copied. Is there a way to copy the cell formatting too? like cell fill color and text formatting?

Comment: @user2901219 About `Thank you. I was able to copy the sheets. I see the values are being copied.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @user2901219 About your new question of `Is there a way to copy the cell formatting too? like cell fill color and text formatting?`, I think that it can be achieved. If you use the above modification, please modify `destinationSheet.getRange(1, index + 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)` to `destinationSheet.getRange(1, index + 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values).setBackgrounds(range.getBackgrounds()).setTextStyles(range.getTextStyles());`.