Google Sheets Script - finding underlined text in a cell
I need to find the underlined text in a cell. I know there is an isUnderlined boolean function for the TextStyle class, but it looks like that is only applicable for Slide. Does anyone know how else I could find where the underlined text in a cell starts and stops? Thanks!
Note that I'm not including code because I know why this approach isn't working. Just need a different approach!

From your following goal,

I need to find the underlined text in a cell. I know there is an isUnderlined boolean function for the TextStyle class, but it looks like that is only applicable for Slide. Does anyone know how else I could find where the underlined text in a cell starts and stops?

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to retrieve the start and end position of the text with the underline in each cell.

In this case, I think that RichText with Google Apps Script can be used. When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following script?
Sample script:
Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and set your sheet name.
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const columnIndexToLetter_ = index => (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter_(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : ""; // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const values = range.getDisplayValues();
  const textStyles = range.getTextStyles();
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues();
  const res = richTextValues.reduce((ar1, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      const underlines = [];
      if (textStyles[i][j].isUnderline()) {
        underlines.push({ start: 0, end: values[i][j].length, wholeTextInCell: true });
      } else {
        underlines.push(...c.getRuns().reduce((ar2, e) => {
          if (e.getTextStyle().isUnderline()) {
            ar2.push({ start: e.getStartIndex(), end: e.getEndIndex(), wholeTextInCell: false });
          }
          return ar2;
        }, []));
      }
      if (underlines.length > 0) {
        ar1.push({ cell: `${columnIndexToLetter_(j)}${i + 1}`, underlines });
      }
    });
    return ar1;
  }, []);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}

Testing:

When this script is used in the above sample Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained in the log.
[
  {"cell":"B1","underlines":[{"start":0,"end":6,"wholeTextInCell":true}]},
  {"cell":"A2","underlines":[{"start":1,"end":4,"wholeTextInCell":false}]},
  {"cell":"C2","underlines":[{"start":0,"end":1,"wholeTextInCell":false},{"start":5,"end":6,"wholeTextInCell":false}]}
]


cell: A cell coordinate as A1Notation.
underlines: When the underline is used to the cell value, the start and the end positions of the underline in the cell text are included.
wholeTextInCell: When this value is true, it means that the underline is used for the whole text in the cell. On the other hand, when this value is false, it means that the underline is used for a part of the text in the cell. You can see it in the above sample image.

Note:

This is a simple sample script for explaining the method for retrieving the underlined texts from the cells. So, please modify this to your actual situation.

References:

getRichTextValues()
isUnderline()

Added 1:
From your following reply,

That's exactly what I have been wanting to use but got the impression it wasn't available for sheets. Do you mind simplifying your code for me for just finding the underlined text in a single cell? That way it would be easier for me to see what you are doing differently that is actually working. –


I also don't need to determine if the whole text is underlined. That will never be the case. I just need to find the start and end position of the text that is underlined in the current highlighted cell.

From your question, I couldn't understand that you don't want to retrieve the cells that the underline is set to the whole text. In order to your reply, it becomes as follows.
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const columnIndexToLetter_ = index => (a = Math.floor(index / 26)) >= 0 ? columnIndexToLetter_(a - 1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + (index % 26)) : ""; // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678158
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues();
  const res = richTextValues.reduce((ar1, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      const underlines = [];
      if (!c.getTextStyle().isUnderline()) {
        underlines.push(...c.getRuns().reduce((ar2, e) => {
          if (e.getTextStyle().isUnderline()) {
            ar2.push({ start: e.getStartIndex(), end: e.getEndIndex(), wholeTextInCell: false });
          }
          return ar2;
        }, []));
      }
      if (underlines.length > 0) {
        ar1.push({ cell: `${columnIndexToLetter_(j)}${i + 1}`, underlines });
      }
    });
    return ar1;
  }, []);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}

When this script is used in the above sample Spreadsheet, the following value is retrieved. The cell "B2" is not included because the underline is set to the whole cell text.
[
  {"cell":"A2","underlines":[{"start":1,"end":4,"wholeTextInCell":false}]},
  {"cell":"C2","underlines":[{"start":0,"end":1,"wholeTextInCell":false},{"start":5,"end":6,"wholeTextInCell":false}]}
]

Added 2:
About your following new request,

Are you able to change the code to just find the underlined text in only ONE cell?

function myFunction() {
  const rangeA1Notation = "'Sheet1'!C2"; // Please set range as a1Notation.

  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  const richTextValue = range.getRichTextValue();
  if (richTextValue.getTextStyle().isUnderline()) return;
  const res = richTextValue.getRuns().reduce((ar, e) => {
    if (e.getTextStyle().isUnderline()) {
      ar.push({ start: e.getStartIndex(), end: e.getEndIndex() });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  console.log(res); // [ { start: 0, end: 1 }, { start: 5, end: 6 } ]
}


When this script is run to the above sample Spreadsheet with const rangeA1Notation = "'Sheet1'!C2";, [ { start: 0, end: 1 }, { start: 5, end: 6 } ] is shown in the log. When it is run with const rangeA1Notation = "'Sheet1'!B1";, no value is shown because the whole text is set as the underline.


Thank you for the example. I'm excited that you got it to work using isUnderlined. That's exactly what I have been wanting to use but got the impression it wasn't available for sheets. Do you mind simplifying your code for me for just finding the underlined text in a single cell? That way it would be easier for me to see what you are doing differently that is actually working.

I also don't need to determine if the whole text is underlined. That will never be the case. I just need to find the start and end position of the text that is underlined in the current highlighted cell.

@Anne Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand that you don't want to retrieve the cells that the underline is set to the whole text. I really apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, I added one more sample script for your actual expected result. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual expected result, I apologize again.

Thank you, Tanaike. You do not need to apologize - your English is good! You have been helpful. Are you able to change the code to just find the underlined text in only ONE cell? It will be easier for me to understand that way. Thank you!

@Anne Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. About your new request Are you able to change the code to just find the underlined text in only ONE cell?, I added one more script. Please confirm it.
