Function to move rows is only moving 1 row instead of all of them
I have a script for Google Sheets that when I click a button, I want it to copy all rows that meet that condition onto a new tab.  Currently it only copies 1 row when clicked and won't copy each one that meets the condition.  Basically I go through column 13 and mark a bunch of rows as true with a checkbox, and after doing so I want to double check them all then click a button to automatically send them all to another tab.  I can't seem to figure out why the button only sends 1 row at a time when clicked.
function moveRows() {
  var mainSheet = "Temp Rack";
  var sheetToMoveTheRow = "Dead Temp Rack";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(sheet.getName() == "Temp Rack" && range.getColumn() == 13 && range.getValue() == true) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dead Temp Rack");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(sheet.getName() == "Dead Temp Rack" && range.getColumn() == 13 && range.getValue() == false) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Temp Rack");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}

I tried the above code, I expected it to move them all, it only moves 1 row.

The script looks very similar to scripts posted on questions about moving a single row, several of them, automatically by using a simple onEdit trigger instead of a button. Still, your use case is different and might face a time execution limit that is exceeded when using a loop to "move" one row at a time because writing and deleting a single row are very slow operations.
Your script uses the SpreadsheetApp.Range.moveTo method. This method "moves" the cell values and the range attributes like borders, background colors, etc.
Try the code below, assuming that you will be moving just a few rows—a number small enough not to exceed the time execution limit.
Code.gs
/** 
 * Name of the source / origin sheet
 * @type {string} 
 */
const SrcSheetName = 'Source';
/**
 * Name of the target / destination sheet 
 * @type {string} 
 */
const TgtSheetName = 'Target';
/**
* Column (1 to 3 A-Z characters) 
* @type {string} 
*/
const CheckboxColumn = 'N';

/**
 * Move rows from one sheet to another
 */
function moveRows() {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const srcSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SrcSheetName);
    const a1Notations = getRowsToMove(srcSheet).map(value => value + ':' + value);
    if(a1Notations.length === 0) { 
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Nothing to move');
      return;
    }
    const rangeList = srcSheet.getRangeList(a1Notations);
    const tgtSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(TgtSheetName);
    rangeList.getRanges().reverse().forEach(row => {
        const tgtRow = tgtSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
        row.moveTo(tgtSheet.getRange(tgtRow, 1));
        srcSheet.deleteRow(row.getRow());
    });
}


/**
 * @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} srcSheet
 * @return {number[]}
 */
function getRowsToMove(srcSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SrcSheetName)) {

    /**
     * Zero-based column index 
     * type {number} 
     */
    const index = letterToColumn(CheckboxColumn) - 1;
    const data = srcSheet.getDataRange()
        .getValues();
    data.forEach((values, i) => values.push(i + 1));
    return data
        .filter(values => values[index] === true)
        .map(values => values.slice(-1))
}
/**
 * Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231012/1595451
 */
function letterToColumn(letter) {
    var column = 0, length = letter.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        column += (letter.charCodeAt(i) - 64) * Math.pow(26, length - i - 1);
    }
    return column;
}


try:
function moveRows() {

  // names of the main and target sheets
  var mainSheetName = "Temp Rack";
  var targetSheetName = "Dead Temp Rack";

  // get the active spreadsheet and sheets based on the names
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName(mainSheetName);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);

  // range of column M in the main sheet (that contains checkboxes)
  var range = mainSheet.getRange("M:M");

  // get the number of rows and values in the range
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // loop through each row in the range
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    
  // check if the checkbox value in the current row is TRUE
  if (values[i][0] == true) {
  
  // get the row number and number of columns in the main sheet
  var row = i + 1;
  var numColumns = mainSheet.getLastColumn();

  // get the target range in the target sheet (next avail. row in column 1)
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

  // move the entire row from the main sheet to the target sheet
  mainSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);

  // delete the moved row from the main sheet
  mainSheet.deleteRow(row);

  // adjust the loop variables to account for the deleted row
  i--;
  numRows--;
}}}

